# Python multiprocessing map_async ready() and _number_left not working as expected

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is a little complicated, and I am sure this is a newbie error, but I cannot for the life for me figure out where to even look.

Trying to do a multiprocessing map_async to process a large number of files.  Essentially, the code gets a list of files, looks in each file for a match on a MAC address and writes out a line to another file if it matches.

nodb is my library....I have not included everything here yet (it's kind of convoluted).  I am hoping that someone can point me where to even look for debugging this.

Here is the problem: the code works perfectly on anything under 60,000 files. However, when I point it at a directory with 595,200 files, the little "while true" loop that checks to see if it is done (using _number_left) stops working....processing appears to continue but the _number_left does not decrease and the ready() function returns TRUE...which it isn't.

And it stops after processing 62111 or 62112 files every single time I run it.  I added the little "dump" function thinking my queue was filling up.

Not sure what else to tell you...am I missing something? (probably)  Please let me know what more I can tell you to figure this out.  I really have no idea what is relevant....

Code is:

```
import nodb_v09d as nodb

import netaddr
import sys
import collections
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import itertools
import time

# Handle CLI arguments
#
nmultip = 1
args = sys.argv[1:]
nmultip = nodb.parseArgs(args)

# this function just gets the file list in the directory
todoPif = nodb.getFileList('/data/david/data/2012/05')

filterfields = { 10:set([int(netaddr.EUI('00-00-0a-0e-c9-be')),\
                         int(netaddr.EUI('00:15:ce:de:78:f3')),\
                         int(netaddr.EUI('3c-75-4a-ea-15-01')),\
                         int(netaddr.EUI('00-24-d1-1e-e9-be'))])
                 }
ff=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(filterfields.items()))

resultfields = [28,29,30,33]
rf=resultfields.sort

cutoff = 40

todocnt = len(todoPif)

outQ = Queue()
hdrQ = Queue()

# output file
gpif = '/media/sf_samplePifs/test2.gpif'

append = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # this is a little trick I picked up off the internet for passing multiple queues.  works ok
    todopool = Pool(None,nodb.poolQueueInit,[outQ,hdrQ])

    # itertools used to create an arg that contains a constant (ff) for all calls)
    r = todopool.map_async(nodb.deRefCall,itertools.izip(todoPif, itertools.repeat(ff)),1)

    while (True):
        nodb.logging.info('number left: ' + str(r._number_left) + '\nready? ' + str(r.ready()))
        nodb.logging.info('queue size: ' + str(outQ.qsize()))

        if (r._number_left == 0): break
        if (outQ.qsize() >= cutoff):
            nodb.dumpQueueToGpif(gpif, hdrQ, outQ, append, cutoff)
            if (append == 0): 
                append = 1

        sys.stderr.write('\rPIF Files DONE: ' + str(todocnt-r._number_left) + '/' + str(todocnt))
        print '\n'
        time.sleep(0.2)
    r.wait()  

sys.stderr.write('\rPIF Files DONE: ' + str(todocnt) + '/' + str(todocnt) + '\n')

# dump remainder to file
nodb.dumpQueueToGpif(gpif, hdrQ, outQ, append,outQ.qsize())
```

**MAJOR ADDITION:**

At the request of another user, I simplified the code.  No queues, no external private libraries, etc:

```
import sys
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def doPifFile(pifFile):

    #readPif = call(['ls','-l',' > /tmp/out'])
    cmd = 'ipdr_dump ' + pifFile + ' | grep "," | wc -l > /tmp/dump'
    readPif = os.system(cmd)
    return readPif

def getFileList(directory):
    flist = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for piffile in files:
            if piffile.endswith('.pif'):
                flist.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root,piffile)))
    return flist

todoPif = getFileList('/data/david/data/2012/05')

todocnt = len(todoPif)
print '# of files to process: ' + str(todocnt)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    todopool = Pool()
    r = todopool.map_async(doPifFile,todoPif,1)

    while (True):
        print 'number left: ' + str(r._number_left) + '\nready? ' + str(r.ready())

        #if (r.ready()): break
        if (r._number_left == 0): break
        sys.stderr.write('\rPIF Files DONE: ' + str(todocnt-r._number_left) + '/' + str(todocnt))
        print '\n'
        time.sleep(0.2)

sys.stderr.write('\rPIF Files DONE: ' + str(todocnt) + '/' + str(todocnt) + '\n')
```

When I ran it, I got something VERY interesting that did NOT show up on the runs with the more complex code but that happened at exactly the same spot, although it claims it happened in my dump program:

```
number left: 533100
ready? False
PIF Files DONE: 62100/595200

number left: 533090
ready? False
PIF Files DONE: 62110/595200

*** glibc detected *** ipdr_dump: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001a58370 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36f5c76126]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36f5c78eb4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(fclose+0x14d)[0x36f5c6678d]
/lib64/libz.so.1[0x36f6803021]
ipdr_dump[0x405c0b]
ipdr_dump[0x40546e]
ipdr_dump[0x401c2a]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x36f5c1ecdd]
ipdr_dump[0x4016b9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2364135                            /home/david/ipdr_dump
0060d000-0060e000 rw-p 0000d000 08:02 2364135                            /home/david/ipdr_dump
01a54000-01a75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
32e0600000-32e0604000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932181                        /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
32e0604000-32e0803000 ---p 00004000 08:02 3932181                        /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
32e0803000-32e0804000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 3932181                        /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
36f5800000-36f5820000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932309                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
36f5a1f000-36f5a20000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 3932309                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
36f5a20000-36f5a21000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 3932309                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
36f5a21000-36f5a22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
36f5c00000-36f5d8a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932315                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36f5d8a000-36f5f89000 ---p 0018a000 08:02 3932315                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36f5f89000-36f5f8d000 r--p 00189000 08:02 3932315                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36f5f8d000-36f5f8e000 rw-p 0018d000 08:02 3932315                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36f5f8e000-36f5f93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
36f6000000-36f6002000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932566                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
36f6002000-36f6202000 ---p 00002000 08:02 3932566                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
36f6202000-36f6203000 r--p 00002000 08:02 3932566                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
36f6203000-36f6204000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 3932566                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
36f6400000-36f6417000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932564                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
36f6417000-36f6617000 ---p 00017000 08:02 3932564                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
36f6617000-36f6618000 r--p 00017000 08:02 3932564                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
36f6618000-36f6619000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 3932564                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
36f6619000-36f661d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
36f6800000-36f6815000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932563                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
36f6815000-36f6a14000 ---p 00015000 08:02 3932563                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
36f6a14000-36f6a15000 r--p 00014000 08:02 3932563                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
36f6a15000-36f6a16000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 3932563                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
36f6c00000-36f6c83000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932493                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
36f6c83000-36f6e82000 ---p 00083000 08:02 3932493                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
36f6e82000-36f6e83000 r--p 00082000 08:02 3932493                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
36f6e83000-36f6e84000 rw-p 00083000 08:02 3932493                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
36f7000000-36f7007000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3935994                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
36f7007000-36f7206000 ---p 00007000 08:02 3935994                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
36f7206000-36f7207000 r--p 00006000 08:02 3935994                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
36f7207000-36f7208000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 3935994                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
36f7800000-36f781d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932588                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
36f781d000-36f7a1c000 ---p 0001d000 08:02 3932588                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
36f7a1c000-36f7a1d000 r--p 0001c000 08:02 3932588                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
36f7a1d000-36f7a1e000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 3932588                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
36f7a1e000-36f7a1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
36f7c00000-36f7c16000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932572                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
36f7c16000-36f7e16000 ---p 00016000 08:02 3932572                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
36f7e16000-36f7e17000 r--p 00016000 08:02 3932572                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
36f7e17000-36f7e18000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 3932572                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
36f7e18000-36f7e1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
36f8000000-36f800e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3935998                        /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f800e000-36f820d000 ---p 0000e000 08:02 3935998                        /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f820d000-36f820e000 r--p 0000d000 08:02 3935998                        /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f820e000-36f820f000 rw-p 0000e000 08:02 3935998                        /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f8800000-36f8849000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3932243                        /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f8849000-36f8a49000 ---p 00049000 08:02 3932243                        /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f8a49000-36f8a4b000 r--p 00049000 08:02 3932243                        /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f8a4b000-36f8a4d000 rw-p 0004b000 08:02 3932243                        /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
36f8c00000-36f8c16000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3936000                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
36f8c16000-36f8e15000 ---p 00016000 08:02 3936000                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
36f8e15000-36f8e16000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 3936000                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
36f9400000-36f9535000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4206136                        /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
36f9535000-36f9734000 ---p 00135000 08:02 4206136                        /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
36f9734000-36f9739000 r--p 00134000 08:02 4206136                        /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
36f9739000-36f973b000 rw-p 00139000 08:02 4206136                        /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
36f973b000-36f973d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
36f9800000-36f9825000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4206135                        /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
36f9825000-36f9a24000 ---p 00025000 08:02 4206135                        /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
36f9a24000-36f9a2a000 r--p 00024000 08:02 4206135                        /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.sonumber left: 533078
ready? False
PIF Files DONE: 62122/595200

number left: 533068
ready? False
PIF Files DONE: 62132/595200

number left: 533056
ready? False
PIF Files DONE: 62144/595200
```

What is odd is that it continued on, whereas the previous runs caused a failure of the _number_left and misfire on "ready()" (although the processes still ran in the background).

I have run the dump program manually on the 16 processor box I have, and they run in parallel fine, never seen that glibc error before.  I have to assume that it is associated with the python setup....I just don't know where.

This may be too complex for a forum diagnosis.  Any further ideas on where I might look or how I might be able to seem what happened are welcome.

One more tidbit...printed out pool._success.  It changes to FALSE at the magic moment with the _number_left stops moving.

```
INFO  number left: 533167  
ready? False  
successful? True  
INFO  queue size: 424  
PIF Files DONE: 62033/595200  

INFO  number left: 533117
ready? False
successful? True
INFO  queue size: 424
PIF Files DONE: 62083/595200

INFO  number left: 533087
ready? True
successful? False
INFO  queue size: 424
PIF Files DONE: 62113/595200

INFO  number left: 533087
ready? True
successful? False
INFO  queue size: 424
PIF Files DONE: 62113/595200
```

Comment: One additional note: I am using 2.7.3 via pypy compiled on the machine.

Comment: Oh, and I did let it run to completion.  Originally, the "while true" loop looked for pool.ready() to be true then it would break out.   The problem was it went true before it was done.  Removing that check let it run to completion, touching all 595k files, but it never left the check loop.  So the "fix" for the code is to remove that check and I think it would complete fine....but there would be no user feedback on the status of the process.

Comment: Can you try to reduce the problem?  Do you still see it in an example not using nodb or netaddr?

Comment: I started creating a short version that just dumps the file...not matching, etc.  Will post results here shortly

Answer (score 1):

After much ado, I have found the problem....as to what causes the problem, I cannot tell yet.  Looks like a bug.

Here are a couple of high level commands so what I explain next makes more sense (this isn't meant to be executable):

```
todopool = Pool()

r = todopool.map_async(myfunction,args,1)

print type(r._value)
```

Recall that args is a list of 595,200 file names.

I started looking at r._value, which in my case is a list of length 595,200.  I noted at the point where the problem arises, the value changed....so I looked at the type.

Here is the output from my most recent run:

```
INFO  number left: 533148 <- based on r._number_left
<type 'list'>             <- print type(r._value)
PIF Files DONE: 62052/595200

INFO  number left: 533096
<type 'list'>
PIF Files DONE: 62104/595200

INFO  number left: 533087
<class 'nodb_v09e.pifReaderEOFReached'>
PIF Files DONE: 62113/595200

INFO  number left: 533087
<class 'nodb_v09e.pifReaderEOFReached'>
PIF Files DONE: 62113/595200
```

All of a sudden r._value, which was a list of length 595,200 is now an exception class.  The odd thing is EVERY run of my subroutine ends up with that exception, so this particular run is no different than any other...it is the way I tell I am at the end of the file.

The change of r._value from a list to a class is what screws up _number_left and my resultant feedback display.  WHY it does it is undetermined.

Comment: Most probably, names starting with underscore (like `_value`) are not supposed to be accessed directly.  If you used some more official interface, I'm sure you'd get more consistent results.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you ever figure out what was going on?

Answer (score 0):

You could try sys.stdout.flush().